# Dynamic css class jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want the link to have a different style on page load. For example, if I click the `About Us` menu item and go to the page I want it show as highlighted to let the user know they are on that page Using jQuery.

I have tried the following code:

```
$("#navigation").click(function()
{
    $('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After triggering 'About Us', your link will change class, but when page will load, all js changes will disappear. You need change class not on click, but onload page, based on your location

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location == '/about') // change about to what you page on
        $('#navigation li a[href=/about]').parent().addClass('current-menu-item'); // change here link too
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list

On the Server side you'll want to keep track which page you are on.  There are many ways you could do this but one way is

```
<ul>
    <li data-link="home">Home</li>
    <li data-link="about">About Us</li>
    <li data-link="contact>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

and if using php for example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPage = "<?= $page ?>";
    $('li[data-link='+currentPage+']').addClass('current-menu-item');
});
```

Handling which link gets the class 'current-menu-item' is much better on the server side but for a quick example i did it using jquery.

Any time you want something done on page load you can place it in $(document).ready
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

**Edit**

One quick and easy way of setting $page is in the page requested itself so...

**about.php**

```
<?php
    $page = "about"
?>
<html>
    ....
</html>
```

There are many ways of doing this so you just need to get creative. That's the beauty of programming :)

Comment: In the php that delivers each of the pages you'll need to specify the page.  So if you have a file called about.php that is your about page you could set $page = "about",  then do the above.  For home.php $page = "home"

Comment: I am fetching the links of Navigation bar from the database using mysqli_fetch_array where i have to specify this $page variable......????

Comment: brother I have tried the above methods..but still its not working....any other solution u can suggest...i hav extensively googled but i get nothing that works......